# Esconder rutas en un sidebar según rol react js

Tags: reactjs, routes

Hola lo que ocurre es que cuando inicio sesión, no sé como filtrar o esconder las rutas en el sidebar según rol, 1 usuario puede tener multiples roles.
Alguien me podría orientar de como hacer de la mejor manera, al iniciar sesión lo redirijo con navigate y la path declarada anteriormente en las routes.

Espero se entienda

Comment: un array con los permisos del usuario , y donde necesites haces permisos.includes('PUEDO_ELIMINAR')&&()

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo hice para resolver esa cuestión es renderizar esas rutas de forma condicional.
Primero obtengo los permisos que tiene el usuario, en mi caso yo los tengo almacenados en un state de Redux.

Después en el componente que tiene mi SideBar condiciono el renderizado del listItem que tiene la ruta que quiero mostrar/ocultar

```
<ListSubheader inset>Administracion</ListSubheader>
      {
//Aqui veo si en mi array de permisos esta el de administración de 
//usuarios con el operador ternario
        permisos.includes('ADMIN_USUARIOS')?(
//si sí esta, renderiza el ListItem
          <ListItem
        button
        onClick={() => {
          navigate('/dashboard/admon/usuarios');
        }}
      >
        <ListItemIcon>
          <SupervisedUserCircleIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Admon Usuarios" />
      </ListItem>
//Si no, solamente mando un array Vacio
        ):[]
      }
      {
        (permisos.includes('ADMIN_MANUALES_TODOS') || permisos.includes('ADMIN_MANUALES_ASIGNADOS'))?(
          <ListItem
        button
        onClick={() => {
          navigate('/dashboard/admon/manuales');
        }}
      >
        <ListItemIcon>
          <SettingsIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Admon Manuales" />
      </ListItem>
        ):[]
      }
```